# Splitting string based with a delimiter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I want to extract the string after the second `_` character and also remove the `(C)` in a Microsoft SQL Server Query.

The field name is Asset Code

Table name is dbo.DynamicsMOJ Data

Data Examples:

Values for Asset Code

```
CP04K_54560_633331 (C)
CP04K_54560_641121 (C)
ME030_72159_690940 (C)
HB21M_60966_1181492 (C)
AW000_1144713 (C)
```

And so forth, all the values in this field are of similar format however some only have a single "_"

I need to get

```
'633331'
'641121'
'690940'
'1181492'
'1144713'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My variants:

```
SELECT
  txt,
  CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(txt)), -- there is 0 for four last examples
  --REPLACE(RIGHT(txt,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(txt))-1,-1),LEN(txt))),' (C)','')
  -- the next variants is better if we have different count of spaces before '(C)'
  RTRIM(REPLACE(RIGHT(txt,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(txt))-1,-1),LEN(txt))),'(C)','')),
  RTRIM(REPLACE(IIF(CHARINDEX('_',txt)=0,txt,RIGHT(txt,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(txt))-1)),'(C)',''))
FROM
  (VALUES
    ('CP04K_54560_633331 (C)'),
    ('CP04K_54560_641121 (C)'),
    ('ME030_72159_690940 (C)'),
    ('HB21M_60966_1181492 (C)'),
    ('AW000_1144713 (C)'),
    (NULL),
    (''),
    ('1234567(C)'),
    ('1234567       (C)'),
    ('1234567')
  ) v(txt)
```

You can check your data using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (VALUES
    ('CP04K_54560_633331 (C)'),
    ('CP04K_54560_641121 (C)'),
    ('ME030_72159_690940 (C)'),
    ('HB21M_60966_1181492 (C)'),
    ('AW000_1144713 (C)'),
    (NULL),
    (''),
    ('1234567(C)'),
    ('1234567       (C)'),
    ('1234567')
  ) v(txt)
WHERE CHARINDEX('_',txt)=0
```

I think it will get you all the values without '_'.

Comment: I wanted to extract the string in the whole Asset Code field which has over 200,000 lines. I tried changing FROM
  (VALUES
    ('CP04K_54560_633331 (C)'),
    ('CP04K_54560_641121 (C)'),
    ('ME030_72159_690940 (C)'),
    ('HB21M_60966_1181492 (C)'),
    ('AW000_1144713 (C)')
  ) v(txt)

To FROM
dbo.DynamicsMOJ Data

Is there anything else that I would need to change in the query to get this to work properly?

Comment: No, it's enough - `SELECT ... FROM dbo.DynamicsMOJ`. And to replace `txt` into your column name.

Comment: When I enter that SQL Query it comes up with an error "Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function."

Comment: @Matthew - I've added several examples and modified the query for specific cases.